# Question from Kline's Calculus: A physical and intuitive approach

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, calculus

A train runs at a velocity of 66 ft/ sec along a straight track. When the brakes are applied, the deceleration is $4/3$  ft/$sec^2$. For how long and how far should the brakes be applied so that the train stops at the station?

(Please note that I have not yet even reached using the integration symbol in this book. It's the complete basics so please do try to explain steps that are simple to you. :-) )

Here's where I'm stuck.

We have initial velocity = 66.

Brake acceleration = - 4/3

Taking the antiderivative of acceleration we get:

v = $-4/3t + C$

When t = 0, v = 66. So, C = 66

v = $-4/3t + 66$

Taking the antiderivative of velocity, we get:

s = $-2/3 t^2 + 66t + C$

Suppose I consider the starting point as distance $0$, then I can say C = $0$ but then I don't know 's' which must be the distance to the station, which is not given.

Suppose I consider the station as distance $0$ then I do not know C as how far the train is from the station is not given.

How do I proceed with this?

Comment: I think you have to assume that the acceleration will start at exactly the right time and place such that the velocity is zero when it reaches the station.  The engineer already knows when to apply the brakes.

Comment: For recommendations of alternative sites which might be suitable see [my question was closed on phys se - can you recommend me another internet site?](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/) You might like to try http://physics.qandaexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

Lets try this:

The equation for deceleration is:

d= (Vf-Vi)/t

Where Vf is the final velocity, which should be zero, having in mind that the train stops in the station.
Vi is the initial velocity, a value given to us by the condition as well as d.

so t= (Vf-Vi)/d= (0-66)/(-4/3)

giving you the time.

Comment: Please do not post complete solutions to homework-like questions.  Our policy on this can be found [here](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/715/5739) which includes:  “If someone posts an answer to a homework-type question that gives away a complete or near-complete solution, in most cases it will be temporarily deleted.”  Please consider deleting this answer yourself.

Comment: But I haven't posted the answer, just pushed him/her in the potentially right direction.